# Can't resolve reference in pycharm when opening a git project

Tags: pycharm

I git clone a project from Github, then I open this folder in Pycharm. However, pycharm can't resolve reference of local module. I mean,such as in `foo.py`

```
import bar # this bar.py is in the same directory as `foo.py`
# pycharm can't resolve bar
# ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess setting the working directory to a source root from "Mark directory as" will solve your problem.

Comment: I try to just open `src` folder, it works. But I don't know why opening the whole project would fail

Comment: @Spaceship222, How is it supposed to know what directory is a sources root?